# Check if div has style height. If yes, don't adjust height

Tags: jquery, css

I have a grandparent div with a fixed height (until css media query decides otherwise).
A parent div where a user can input a height (mostly percentage values, in a rare occasion px values)
Child div's where a user can enter percentage and px values.

What I try to accomplish:

1. If a user hasn't defined a value for the parent div, all children div's need to follow with their natural content height.
2. If a user has defined a value for the parent div, and no values for the children, all child div's should be divided equally.

1 and 2 are covered.

Now I'm trying to wrap my head around the following:

3. If a value is entered for the parent div, all child div's should be divided equally, except for the child div's where a value is entered. That value should be respected.

I got the following fiddle with what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/andyderuyter/qepqdmer/

```js
$('.child').each(function() {

  var aantalDivs = $(".child").length;
  var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
  var childNewHeight = parentHeight / aantalDivs;
  var hasHeight = $(this).height().length;

  if (parentHeight == 700) {
    $('.child').height(childNewHeight);
  }

});
```

```css
.grandparent {
  height: 700px;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.child-1 {
  background-color: orange;
}
.child-2 {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}
.child-3 {
  background-color: violet;
}
.vertical {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child child-1">
      <div class="vertical">Div 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-2">
      <div class="vertical">Div 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child child-3" style="height:25%;">
      <div class="vertical">Div 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain 3rd point little more?
"except for the child div's where a value is entered. That value should be respected"

Comment: .child-3 has a height of 25%, so if the parent is 100% (700px because of grandparent) both .child-1 and .child-2 should have a calculated height by jQuery and .child-3 should stay 25% high.

Comment: Do you only want to filter out elements where the height was specifically set in the style tag of the element, or also if it was set through css? To filter elements set in the style tag you could use an attribute filter like `[style*=height]` (example: http://jsfiddle.net/qepqdmer/1/ )

Comment: This is what I wanted to accomplish! Can you set this as an answer?

Comment: Okidoki. Done. Had expected that you'd also need to check if it contained a css height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the goal is to set a fixed height for all divs not containing a direct height set in a style tag (so not including anything set through css), you can use a jquery attribute filter such as `[style*=height]`:

```
var childdivs = $('.child'); //get all child elements
var height = childdivs.parent().height();
var withheight = childdivs.filter('[style*=height]'); //get all elements with a style tag containing height
withheight.each(function(){height-=$(this).height();}); //subtract those heights from parentheight
var otherdivs = childdivs.not(withheight); //get all other elements (without height tag)
otherdivs.height(height/otherdivs.length); //set all elements to parentheight/otherelementcount
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qepqdmer/1/)

As mentioned by others, it's probably better handled if classes are used to manipulate custom heights, even if done so by the user, but the above should work for the specific example.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, because now the parent div will be filled 100% with child div's. Even if a child div has a certain height applied, this will be respected by the code provided. Thank you Me.Name!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class when you set the height so you will be able to use a hasClass() on the div to know if the height is set.

OR

You can use the attr('style') and serch for height.

```js
function isHeightSet(styletext){
  if(typeof styletext != 'undefined'){
    testStyleL = styletext.toLowerCase(),
    testH = testStyleL.indexOf('height'),
    test1 = false;
    if(testH >= 0){
       return true;
    }
  } 
  return false;
}

var test1Style = $('.test1').attr('style'),
test1 = isHeightSet(test1Style);

var test2Style = $('.test2').attr('style');
test2 = isHeightSet(test2Style);

$('.test1').html('Height : '+test1Style + '/' + test1);
$('.test2').html('Height : '+test2Style + '/' + test2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1" style="Height:120px;">Test1</div>
<div class="test2" ><span>Test2</span></div>
```

Comment: I update your jsFiffle http://jsfiddle.net/001z9xvk/2/ . You has set your height to all the child. it worked like if one of the .child didn't have the class you setted the height to all the .child so change I change the $('.child').height for $(this).height.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I accepted Me.name's answer as solving answer. Even though, your code works, it is a little less elegant. I really appreciate the answer though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I update your jsFiffle http://jsfiddle.net/001z9xvk/2/ . You had set your height to all the **.child**. It worked like if one of the **.child** didn't have the class you settled the height to all the **.child** so change I change the `$('.child').height` for `$(this).height`.